# How to predict unknown(hidden) value by incomplete value or partly recorded value

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, probability

Let me make it clear by make an example:

Suppose I knew a person's cost each month for 3 years like:

2016Jan : $2500

2016Feb : $4000

2016Mar : $3500
...

Just according to this, can I predict how much he earned each month in these years? If I could, what model should use? If I couldn't, what info I need to make this possible. If I couldn't guess in 100 percent but I could guess by some probability, what model should I use?

Another example: 
Need to estimate how much each store sells in each city, however I could only got the sales when they record it in electric system, if they didn't record it in electric system(may use paper or something else); then I don't know, how can I get all sales, not just the sales record in electric system?

Any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use almost any regression model. When you do not want to go too much into theory simply use a gaussian process provided by [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor). This model gives you predictions and uncertainties.

Comment: Thanks for let me know the gaussian process by sklearn

Comment: According to my understanding these days, GP need a prior (x,y), to build on (x*,y*), however, in my case, I don't have any y, what I have is only x and x*, any further ideas?

Comment: You can use the month (jan., feb., etc..) as your $x$ and the income as your $y$. Afterwards you calculate for missing $x$ your corresponding $y$ with the gp.

Comment: I don't have any income data, I only have person's living cost